# Unexpected behaviour by pointer (when manipulated) but defined behaviour when using a double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, sdl-2

I'm quite confused about the reasoning behind the behaviour of pointers to a variable. I would have thought that if I append a pointer to a `vector` and access it, whether I changed the pointer itself it should still work the same upon the same variable. What I mean by this is, for example, I have a vector of integer pointers and I modify a variable defined somewhere else that has been appended to the vector. If I was to then print them, it should update the vector (not in reality) but it should print the new value of an integer. I'm trying to apply this to an `SDL_Texture*` in SDL2, however it doesn't quite make sense. In summary, the same concept is applying there however I am using Textures instead. I modify the texture and do "things" with it, but at the end of the loop when I render it, the vector is still iterating to the `SDL_Texture*` appended to it anyway. What my problem is, is as I change and modify the texture, when I go to render it it doesn't show up. This isn't because the texture isn't properly loaded or anything (I have tested it and rather than using the vector, I draw it raw) but when using the vector it doesn't work properly. Here is the code:

```
void Main::Mainloop()
{

    Screen_Object m_Screen_Object;

    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("Anonymous_Pro.ttf", 30);
    SDL_Surface* surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, "Starting fps", {0,0,0});
    SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Render::Get_Renderer(), surf);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    SDL_Rect rct = {20, 100, 0,0};
    SDL_QueryTexture(tex, NULL, NULL, &rct.w, &rct.h);
    m_Screen_Object.Add_Texture(tex);


    Uint32 start, finish, counter;
    counter = 0;
    start = SDL_GetTicks();
    finish = SDL_GetTicks();



    bool running = true;

    while (running)
    {
        Events::Event_Loop();
        if (Events::Quit_Application()){
            running = false;
            break;
        }


        ///Clear display to color
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Render::Get_Renderer(), 0,255,0,255);
        SDL_RenderClear(Render::Get_Renderer());



        ///Do stuff here
        m_Screen_Object.Draw_Textures();
        

        finish = SDL_GetTicks();
        counter += 2;
        if (finish - start >= 500)
        {
            start = SDL_GetTicks();

            SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
            std::string fps = std::to_string(counter);
            surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, fps.c_str(), {0,0,0});
            tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Render::Get_Renderer(), surf);
            SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
            SDL_QueryTexture(tex, NULL, NULL, &rct.w, &rct.h);
            counter = 0;
        }


        SDL_RenderPresent(Render::Get_Renderer());

    }


    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);

}




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Main::Mainloop();

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the declaration of `Screen_Object`:
**In the header:**

```
std::vector < SDL_Texture* > m_Textures;
```

**In the .cpp:**

```
void Screen_Object::Add_Texture(SDL_Texture* p_Texture)
{
    m_Textures.push_back(p_Texture);
}


void Screen_Object::Draw_Textures()
{

    for (unsigned int i=0; i < m_Textures.size(); i++)
    {
        SDL_RenderCopy(Render::Get_Renderer(), m_Textures[i], NULL, &m_Rect);
    }

}
```

Now this code doesn't work in the way I believe it should since I can't understand why it isn't working, but when I change the vector's type to be `SDL_Texture**`, the code works fine. What on earth is wrong with the code without the `**`, I just can't logically understand why it won't work properly

Comment: *I'm quite confused about the reasoning behind the behaviour of pointers to a variable.* -- It would have been much easier to put together a very simple, standard, C++ program, without SDL, that shows the issue.  Something simple using pointers to `int`, etc. instead of full blown SDL types.

Comment: Because it works with ```int``` but not with an ```SDL_Texture*```

Comment: Show us the `int` version you say "works".

Comment: Here:```#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int val = 50;
    std::vector < int* > myInts;
    myInts.push_back(&val);
    val = 100;
    std::cout << *myInts[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: output is 100, not 50

Comment: Code in comments does not work. Please [edit].

Comment: Your vector stores copy of data you push to it. You modify your local `tex` but not the copy in vector. Pointer is just a variable, it don't have special meaning here. So, if you vector stores `int`, it stores copy of int. If it stores `int*`, it stores copy of `int*`. Value if `int` it points to could be changed indirectly, but not the address itself.

Comment: If thats the case that it stores a copy of the variable, pointer or not, why does manipulating the adress for ints work but not an```SDL_Texture*```? @keltar

Comment: `m_Screen_Object.Add_Texture(tex, &rct);` -- The function call has two arguments, but the function itself only takes one argument.

Comment: @asdfgodsia123e890dik in case of ints, you've modified your `int` value. In case of `SDL_Texture`, you never did that - instead you've created new texture and assigned new address to your pointer. You can do the same with `vector<int*>` and setting `new int`.

Comment: `tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Render::Get_Renderer(), surf);` -- The vector has no idea you've messed around with `tex`.  The vector now contains a junk pointer value after this.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow correctly, for the ints that makes sense, but I never did anything different with the ```SDL_Texture```, Its still under the same variable name, just the SDL2 functions modify the variable  @keltar

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how is that any different to the ```int``` example

Comment: *Its still under the same variable name,* -- Bingo.  You are looking at the `name` instead of looking at the `value`.  It is the value that counts, not the name.

Comment: AHhhh I think i finally understand now. Would double pointer still then be the correct way to go for what I need it to do

Comment: @asdfgodsia123e890dik `vector<int*> v; int *a = new int; *a = 0; v.push_back(a); a = new int; *a = 1;` - same thing as you did with textures, basically.

Comment: Why are you not getting the value from the vector itself and changing it if necessary?   Isn't that the repository where the pointer is kept/updated/manipulated?  Why hang on to `tex`?  Once you place `tex` in the vector, then `m_Textures.back()` gives you a reference to the pointer you added.

Comment: Its under a ```Screen_Objects``` class, i'm still somewhat new to good structuring but I envisioned that I would just append the pointers to the textures to the vector so I don't have to manually type out ```RenderCopy()``` for each texture, rather I just add them to a vector and it iterates through all the textures it needs to draw

Comment: For the original question @keltar, PaulMcKenzie thats pretty clear what the problem is, thanks

Comment: The problem is pointer invalidation -- the vector (and it doesn't need to be a vector) has no indication that you've pulled the rug out from the pointer and changed it.  If you debugged, you would see that `vector` still has the same pointer value, but it is dead.  Maybe `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>>` would be a better choice in this situation?

Comment: What does it mean that the pointer is shared / what would that change? Also is that ```<SDL_Texture>``` or ```<SDL_Texture*>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are storing pointers in the vector, but outside the vector you are invalidating the pointer.

```
void Screen_Object::Add_Texture(SDL_Texture* p_Texture)
{
    m_Textures.push_back(p_Texture);
}

void Main::Mainloop()
{
    Screen_Object m_Screen_Object;
    //...
    SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Render::Get_Renderer(), surf);
    //...
    m_Screen_Object.Add_Texture(tex); // <-- add pointer to vector
    //...
    tex =  SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Render::Get_Renderer(), surf); // <-- This changes the pointer, but has no effect on the vector's 
    //...
```

So anything after that line, if you access the pointer in `m_Textures` vector, that pointer in the vector is no longer valid, or worse, it is valid, but points to an old (but still valid) `SDL_Texture`.

A very simple solution is to ensure that you use the pointer you stored in the `m_Textures` by obtaining a reference to that pointer:

```
void Main::Mainloop()
{
    Screen_Object m_Screen_Object;

    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("Anonymous_Pro.ttf", 30);
    SDL_Surface* surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, "Starting fps", {0,0,0});

    SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Render::Get_Renderer(), surf);
    m_Screen_Object.Add_Texture(tex);  // <-- Immediately do this
    auto& texRef = m_Screen_Object.back(); // <-- Get a reference to the pointer.
```

Then you use `texRef` after that.  This is the actual reference to the pointer you added to the vector, and not a copy of the pointer.

Then the loop would be simply:

```
 texRef = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Render::Get_Renderer(), surf);
```

This changes the actual pointer stored in the vector.

Comment: what would a ```shared_ptr``` help with, I just sort of looked into it but I don't quite understand how to apply it to an ```SDL_Texture```

Comment: It probably wouldn't help here.  But a `shared_ptr` is basically a reference-counted pointer -- the last entity that has a reference to the pointer, when it dies off, the pointer automatically gets "deleted".  You would use it if you had an `SDL_Texture` being shared, and there is no clear ownership established as to who is responsible in cleaning up once done with it -- the texture will just die off when the shared_ptr to it detects there are no more references to it.

Comment: Just so we clear - `texRef` (or any other pointer/reference to vector stored data) is only valid until next reallocation of vector. E.g. inserting new element to vector may invalidate reference without any notification. Something to be aware of.

Comment: Yes, the reference is no longer valid if the vector reallocates.  The pointer value itself is still ok, but not the reference to the pointer.